# Section within a section for UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have to create a UITableView that has sections within sections however I have never done this before and am not even sure if this is possible.

This is what it needs to look like

- Header 1

  - Sub Header 1

    - cell 1
    - cell 2
    - cell 3
  - Sub Header 2

    - cell 1
    - cell 2
- Header 2

  - Sub Header 1

    - cell 1
  - Sub Header 2

    - cell 1
    - cell 2

All fields are dynamic, so there could be 0 or more Header sections; would a UITableView be the best way to go about this? if so how would I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do it, you have to plan cleverly.

From `numberOfSectionsInTableView` return the number of "Header".

For each section in `numberOfRowsInSection` return Sub Header + Cell in each sub header.

From `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just chek if it is a sub header or a cell. If its is a sub header the return a cell which has a Label near to left side, if it is a cell then return a cell that has the label in more far away from left border.

You can use same cell just changing the frame of the cell's label.